# Parsing id3 data from a local audio file within firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, id3

I'm developing a `Firefox addon` using the `SDK`, which lists audio files on your computer using `require("sdk/io/file").list()`.
I build an array of file paths using the method above and pass this array to a `contentScript` attached to a `Panel`.
The `Panel` then loops through the array and displays all the files found.

Now I'm trying to use [JavaScript-ID3-Reader](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader) so I can read `ID3` data from each file and display this data alongside each file.
I've been trying [this](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader#file-api) (read local files), from inside the `contentScript` e.g ..

```
var f = new File([""], "file:///home/user/audio.mp3");
ID3.loadTags("audio.mp3", function () {
        var tags = ID3.getAllTags("audio.mp3");
        console.log(tags.comment + " - " + tags.track + ", " + tags.lyrics);
}, {
        dataReader: FileAPIReader(f)
});
```

But the output I get is ..

```
undefined - undefined, undefined
```

`/home/user/audio.mp3` contains the following `ID3` data, found with http://web.ist.utl.pt/antonio.afonso/www.aadsm.net/libraries/id3/ ..

```
Artist
    A Perfect Circle
Title
    Annihilation
Album
    eMOTIVe
Year
    2004
Comment
Genre
    Pop/Rock
Track
    1/12
Lyrics
```

Here is another test I was trying ..

```
function getID3 (file) {
        var url = file.name;
        console.log(url); // console.log: addon: /home/user/audio.mp3
        ID3.loadTags(url, function () {
                var tags = ID3.getAllTags(url);
                console.log(tags); // console.log: addon: {}
                console.log(tags.artist); // console.log: addon: null
        }, {
                dataReader: new FileAPIReader(file)
        });
}

var f = new File([""], "file:///home/rob/audio.mp3", {type : "audio/mpeg"});
getID3(f);
```

Anyone know what might be wrong with this? `/home/user/audio.mp3` does exist on file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JavaScript-ID3-Reader library is meant to run in the context of a website, only for files available via `http` and `https` afaict.

You might want to find a library which will work on the add-on side.

Comment: do `contentScripts` attached to `Panels` not run in website context? Since I attached the lib during `Panel` creation I thought it would have access to local files similiar to how `<audio> src` on a `contentURL` of `Panel` can access local files.

Comment: `contentScript`s run in a sandbox with the almost same privileges (using an extended principal) as the website itself. It's almost the same as a regular `<script>` import but not quite the same due to xray wrappers. Some scripts break under those conditions. You either should use a different script or try injecting it into the page content itself if that doesn't pose any security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your audio.mp3 file has these ID3 tags defined? Try listing your ID3 tags using console.log(tags) to see them all, and also try opening it with a desktop media player to see if the information shows up. Note that there are several different versions of ID3, so you may be using the wrong version too.

Comment: Some data is there, I've ran the test provided by lib, [here](http://web.ist.utl.pt/antonio.afonso/www.aadsm.net/libraries/id3/), for checking `ID3` tags and the results are `{"Track": "1/12", "Comment":"", "Lyrics": ""}`. So using `console.log(tags)` should print something instead of `{}`, right?